# Modal close with transition effects on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal which is opened by clicking this hyperlink:

```
<a class="link-efekt" data-hover="izrazi zanimanje" href="#izrazi-zanimanje-univerzalno">izrazi zanimanje</a>
```

And closed by clicking this one:

```
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" data-hover="zapri">zapri</a>
```

I am trying to reprogram the ESC key to always go back to the main screen back to the main screen or to close modal window.

So my attempt at this was to reprogram ESC key to go to a previous hyperlink using `window.history.back();` but then it can go back multiple times and I only want it to be able to go back once - just enough to close modal window. This is why i implemented the if statement which should check if `#izrazi-zanimanje-univerzalno` is opened. Otherwise ESC key shouldn't do anything.

I also tried using `$('#izrazi-zanimanje-univerzalno').hide();` instead of `window.history.back()` (without if sentence) but it totally ignores my CSS transition effects and once modal is hidden it can't be respawned by clicking on a hyperlink that usually opens it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            if ( $("#izrazi-zanimanje-univerzalno").data('modal').isShown ) {
                 window.history.back();                                   
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

---

After implementing the first suggested solution by @crazymatt I get this console output on keypress:

[image]

Comment: The error in my question was from using **slim** version of Jquery instead of normal one. **They aren't the same!**

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out and no they are not the same :-)

Comment: I thought that the slim one is just written in a more condensed fashion. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JQuery couldn't you run a fade animation then close the window? Something like this:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function() {
    // Animation complete now close overlay
  });
});
```

I [made a JS.Fiddle with my example](https://jsfiddle.net/t19mrych/) but I didn't take the time to apply this to an overlay.

Comment: I tried using `$( "#izrazi-zanimanje-univerzalno" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function(){});` in place of `window.history.back();` and without if sentance, but it didn't work.

Comment: @71GA are you seeing an error in the console or anything? It may be helpful if you post more of your code, like the trigger to open and close your modal and the HTML

Comment: I added the description on how my modal is usually closed. I also added console output on keypress (if I use your solution).

Comment: @71GA its hard to tell what is going on without seeing an example or more of you code. Is there anyway you can reproduce the issue in a js.fiddle or codepen?